# Changing the local Ivy repository used by Ant script

Tags: ant, ivy

Is it possible to change the location of a local Ivy repository? This repository is currently referenced in an Ant script.

Now it's in `c:\Users\username\.ivy2\`. I'd like to move it to another disk.

Is there any system variable (like with Gradle) or some location tag in some .xml file (like with Maven)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following documentation page describes the default settings in ivy.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html

To override the location fo the local repository set the value of the following property:

- ivy.local.default.root